# msteams: custom app with read messages permission

Tags: microsoft-teams

There are 3 types of MSTeams app: tabs, bot or message extensions
I want to create an application that can read chat like https://www.m.io/ does, so which type is recommended and what permission to add to the manifest file in order to allow the app to read the messages?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement, so that we can investigate it from our end?

Comment: the problem is that Microsoft's documentation is not straightforward, I want to create an MSTeams app that can simply read chats and conversations. I don't know which type to use ( tabs, bot or message extensions) and what permission to add in order to allow it to read messages!

Comment: You can use the Bot. Here is sample bot conversation-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation/csharp

Comment: thanks for sharing that, but it looks like u can add the bot to one conversation or one channel am I right? but in my case I want to add to many channels and many conversations. is it possible?

Comment: Did not get you exact point. as per my understanding you want to add at a time the bot in many channels. please suggest more on it, if i am wrong?